# Get method does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Beeing new to ASP.NET I'm following this [tutorial at www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer). But I get a problem when writing the `public class ProductDatabaseInitializer`

I wrote the ProductContext.cs class as follow

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WingtipToys.Models
{
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductContext() : base("WingtipToys")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
}
```

But get error writing the ProductDatabaseInitializer.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WingtipToys.Models
{
public class ProductDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProductContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ProductContext context)
    {
        GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));// <-here
        GetProducts().ForEach(p => context.Products.Add(p));    // <-here
    }
}
}
```

On the `GetCategories()` and the `GetProducts()` I get error "does not exist in the current context".

The Category class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WingtipToys.Models
{
public class Category
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name ="Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Product Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
}
```

The Product class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WingtipToys.Models
{
public class Product
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name ="Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(10000), Display(Name ="Product Description"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    public double? UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just checked that tutorial, and have seen a missing bit from your code.

There is a private static method `GetCategories()` in the database initialiser, which would need to be added to use your code in its current state.

Check through the tutorial in the section for the Initialiser class, and add the missing methods.

If these methods have already been added, it's possible that they have the wrong method declaration (they must be static), or they have a typo in the names (not uncommon, especially if you're typing them out by hand).

```
   private static List<Category> GetCategories() {
       var categories = new List<Category> {
            new Category
            {
                CategoryID = 1,
                CategoryName = "Cars"
            },
            // The rest of the categories here...
        };

        return categories;
    }
```

Note that you can use the type to initialise this field (in a much nearer way than using a method).

This took me some time to get used to coming from a Java background where we had to write get/set methods.

EDIT -

```
private static List<Category> _categories;
public static List<Category> Categories {
    get {
        _categories = new List<Category> {
            new Category
            {
                CategoryID = 1,
                CategoryName = "Cars"
            }
        };
        return _categories;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
public ProductContext() : base("WingtipToys")
{
}
public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

protected override void Seed(ProductContext context)
{
    GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));// <-here
    GetProducts().ForEach(p => context.Products.Add(p));    // <-here
}
```

Here You no need to call `GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));` because GetCategories() is an method and you din't define any method of that name, here you can directly call foreach on DbSet object like `Categories.ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));`